# password generator - letter check

Tags: python

I am trying to build a password generator that would give me passwords that consist of lower case, upper case, numbers and special characters. Below is my code. It generates passwords to the required length but these do not contain characters from each group. Please can someone help to explain what I did wrong?

Many thanks.

```
    import random

    lower_case = list("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
    upper_case = list("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".upper())
    num = []
    for i in range(0, 10):
        num.append(i)
    s_letters = ["_", "@", "."]
    available_char = lower_case + upper_case + num + s_letters



def set_password():
    password_gen(length())


def length():
    user_l = input("Please enter length of password. Minimum 6.\n")

    try:
        int(user_l) >= 6
    except:
        print("invalid number")
        length()
    return int(user_l)



def password_gen(x):
    password = []
    for i in range(x):
        character = random.choice(available_char)
        password.append(str(character))

    set_a = set(password)
    while True:
        valid = True
        if set_a & set(lower_case) == {}:
            password_gen(x)
            valid = False
        if set_a & set(upper_case) == {}:
            password_gen(x)
            valid = False
        if set_a & set(num) == {}:
            password_gen(x)
            valid = False
        if set_a & set(s_letters) == {}:
            password_gen(x)
            valid = False
        if valid:
            print("Your password is " + "".join(password))
            print(set_a & set(lower_case))
            print(set_a & set(upper_case))
            print(set_a & set(num))
            print(set_a & set(s_letters))
            break

set_password()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your method `length` does not give assure the number is `>=6` because the statement `int(user_l) >= 6` doesn't raise an Exception, you may use `assert int(user_l) >= 6`, but rather than calling the method again and again, use a while loop

   ```
   def length():
       user_l = input("Please enter length of password. Minimum 6.\n")
       while not user_l.isdigit() or int(user_l) < 6:
           user_l = input("Please enter length of password. Minimum 6.\n")
       return int(user_l)
   ```
2. Use a method to build the password, and another one to validate it

   ```
   def generate_pwd(length):
       password = []
       for i in range(length):
           character = random.choice(available_char)
           password.append(str(character))
       return password
   ```
3. The `{}` is empty dict, not empty `set`, also you can use the boolean value `False` of an empty `set` , and use `elif` to avoid doing all the `if` is one is fase don't do the next ones

   ```
   if not set_a & set(ascii_lowercase)
   ```
4. The more readable way would be the other : if all condition are True, the password is valid

   ```
   valid = set_a & set(ascii_lowercase) and set_a & set(ascii_uppercase) and \
           set_a & set(digits) and set_a & set(s_letters)
   ```

---

Here's the full code that uses built-in alphabet from `string`

```
import random
from string import ascii_lowercase, ascii_uppercase, digits

s_letters = ["_", "@", "."]
available_char = list(ascii_lowercase) + list(ascii_uppercase) + list(digits) + s_letters

def set_password():
    password_gen(length())

def length():
    user_l = input("Please enter length of password. Minimum 6.\n")
    while not user_l.isdigit() or int(user_l) < 6:
        user_l = input("Please enter length of password. Minimum 6.\n")
    return int(user_l)

def generate_pwd(length):
    return [str(random.choice(available_char)) for i in range(length)]

def password_gen(length):
    valid = False
    password = []
    set_a = set()
    while not valid:
        password = generate_pwd(length)
        set_a = set(password)
        valid = set_a & set(ascii_lowercase) and set_a & set(ascii_uppercase) and \
                set_a & set(digits) and set_a & set(s_letters)

    print("Your password is " + "".join(password))
    print(set_a & set(ascii_lowercase))
    print(set_a & set(ascii_uppercase))
    print(set_a & set(digits))
    print(set_a & set(s_letters))
```

Comment: Thanks azro. What is the difference between repeating a method and using a while loop?

Comment: @LYCbecause the is not just repetiting, this is recursivity and you'll have to handle result in all the caller after, so don't re-call a method for re-doing it, the method should handl the problem on its own

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could create another list of keys corresponding to each character type (e.g. `char_type = [“number”, “special”, “lowercase”, “uppercase”]`).  Then, prior to choosing a random item from one of those lists, you can randomly choose an item from your “char_type” list.  As you approach your desired lengths, you can have checks in place to ensure that if a required type does not yet exist in the string, it will be added prior to hitting the desired character length.

Something like this:

```
import random

character_types = {}
character_types["lower_case"] = list("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
character_types["upper_case"] = [char.upper() for char in character_types["lower_case"]]
character_types["num"] = [str(i) for i in range(0, 10)]
character_types["s_letters"] = ["_", "@", "."]
character_types["types"] = [key for key in character_types.keys()]
# available_char = lower_case + upper_case + num + s_letters


def set_password():
    password_gen(length())


def length():
    user_l = input("Please enter length of password. Minimum 6.\n")


    if not int(user_l) >= 6:
        print("invalid number")
        length()
    return int(user_l)


def password_gen(x):
    password = []
    password_types = set()
    required_types = 4
    for i in range(x):
        char_type = random.choice(character_types["types"])
        if x - len(password) <= 4:
            if "s_letters" not in password_types:
                char_type = "s_letters"
            elif "lower_case" not in password_types:
                char_type = "lower_case"
            elif "upper_case" not in password_types:
                char_type = "upper_case"
            elif "num" not in password_types:
                char_type = "num"

        character = random.choice(character_types[char_type])
        password_types.add(char_type)
        password.append(character)

    set_a = set(password)
    # while True:
    #     valid = True
    #     if set_a & set(lower_case) == {}:
    #         password_gen(x)
    #         valid = False
    #     if set_a & set(upper_case) == {}:
    #         password_gen(x)
    #         valid = False
    #     if set_a & set(num) == {}:
    #         password_gen(x)
    #         valid = False
    #     if set_a & set(s_letters) == {}:
    #         password_gen(x)
    #         valid = False
    #     if valid:
    print("Your password is " + "".join(password))
    print(set_a & set(character_types["lower_case"]))
    print(set_a & set(character_types["upper_case"]))
    print(set_a & set(character_types["num"])) # This was initially not working because num did not consist of strings, whereas the password did.
    print(set_a & set(character_types["s_letters"]))
    # break


set_password()
```

There is no need for the final checks because the rules prevent an invalid password from ever being created.  This also prevents us from repeatedly generating passwords such that we may find a valid one.

@azro is also correct in mentioning that your length check does not prevent someone from choosing a length less than 6 (fixed above).

There is an improvement you could make to the above code. Currently, when it checks to make sure all required types exist in the password, it is doing so in a fixed order.  As such, it will always append the missing character types in the same order (if none of them exist in the string already).  You could instead, determine at each step of the way which character types are missing (maintain a list of "missing_types" or something), and then randomly choose a type from a list, and then randomly select a character based on the chosen type.

Comment: I thought of that too, but as you mentioned it already, I shall not leave an asnwer. Thumbs up.